# MemoryStream analog in Python

Tags: c#, python, memorystream

Does some analog of C# `MemoryStream` exist in Python (that could allow me to write binary data from some source direct into memory)? And how would I go about using it?

Comment: Are you asking about `StringIO`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

StringIO is one possibility: http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html

> This module implements a file-like class, `StringIO`, that reads and writes a string buffer (also known as *memory files*). See the description of file objects for operations (section *File Objects*). (For standard strings, see `str` and `unicode`.)...

Comment: Or `cStringIO`, which is the same but is implemented in C for speed.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Python >= 3.0 and tried out [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216530/834176), you will notice that `import StringIO` or `import cStringIO` both give an import error. This is because StringIO is [now part of the `io` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18284900/834176).

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import StringIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'
>>> # Huh? Maybe this will work...
... 
>>> import cStringIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'cStringIO'
>>> # Whaaaa...?
... 
>>> import io
>>> io.StringIO
<class '_io.StringIO'>
>>> # Oh, good!
...
```

You can use [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html#io.StringIO) just as if it was a regular Python file: `write()`, `close()`, and all that jazz, with an additional `getvalue()` to retrieve the string.