# How do you use StringIO in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I am using Python 3.2.1 and I can't import the `StringIO` module. I use
`io.StringIO` and it works, but I can't use it with `numpy`'s `genfromtxt()` like this:

```py
x="1 3\n 4.5 8"        
numpy.genfromtxt(io.StringIO(x))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

and when I write `import StringIO` it says

```
ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'
```

Answer (score 1075):

> when i write import StringIO it says there is no such module.

From [What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html):

> The `StringIO` and `cStringIO` modules are gone. Instead, import the `io`
> module and use `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` for text and data
> respectively.

.

---

A possibly useful method of fixing some Python 2 code to also work in Python 3 (caveat emptor):

```
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO ## for Python 2
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO ## for Python 3
```

> *Note: This example may be tangential to the main issue of the question and is included only as something to consider when generically addressing the missing `StringIO` module.*  For a more direct solution the message `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11970414/86967).

Comment: Worth mentioning these are not the same, so you can end up with `TypeError`s ( string argument expected, got 'bytes') if you make this change in isolation. You need to carefully distinguish btyes and str (unicode) in python 3.

Comment: For newbs like me: from io import StringIO means you call it as StringIO(), not io.StringIO().

Comment: How to actually be compatible with Python 2 and 3: just `from io import StringIO`

Comment: THIS IS SIMPLY WRONG for numpy.genfromtxt() in python 3. Please refer to the answer from Roman Shapovalov.

Comment: @realtemper: Do you mean that the first part of the answer is wrong (it's a quote from the docs), or that the example doesn't apply to the question.

Comment: @nobar: The latter. The original question uses python 3.x, from which the module `StringIO` is gone and `from io import BytesIO` should be applied instead. Tested myself on python 3.5 @ eclipse pyDev + win7 x64. Please let me know if I were wrong thanks.

Comment: Seconding @realtemper. This answered the question I googled, but not the question OP asked. (Presumably that is why it has all the upvotes.)

Comment: @josePhoenix: RomanShapovalov had already answered part of the question.  I just provided a bit more information (from the docs), which directly addressed a different aspect of the question: "I can't import the StringIO module".

Comment: I can't vouch for the example because it was added by someone else and I haven't tested it, but it looks like it is a general example of how to write an import that will work with both Python2 and Python3.  The example is probably not a direct solution to the numpy aspect of the question.

Comment: Please delete this answer, it is misleading. Downvoted.

Comment: @OlehPrypin: It didn't turn out to be compatible for me. [Python 2 `io.StringIO` only supported unicode strings, not 8-bit strings.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2013-May/648248.html)

Comment: @HelgaIliashenko This answer doesn't deserve downvotes. In an ideal world the other answer simply has more upvotes.

Comment: @ImperishableNight in an ideal world, this answer does not exist anymore.

Comment: Worked for me like a charm!

Comment: @AndyHayden, so I encountered the issue you mentioned, but how to adderss this?

Comment: [Six is a Python 2 and 3 compatibility library.](https://pypi.org/project/six/)

Answer (score 174):

In my case I have used:

```
from io import StringIO
```

Answer (score 79):

On Python 3 `numpy.genfromtxt` expects a bytes stream. Use the following:

```
numpy.genfromtxt(io.BytesIO(x.encode()))
```

Answer (score 27):

Roman Shapovalov's code should work in Python 3.x as well as Python 2.6/2.7. Here it is again with the complete example:

```py
import io
import numpy
x = "1 3\n 4.5 8"
numpy.genfromtxt(io.BytesIO(x.encode()))
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1. ,  3. ],
       [ 4.5,  8. ]])
```

Explanation for Python 3.x:

- `numpy.genfromtxt` takes a byte stream (a file-like object interpreted as bytes instead of Unicode).
- `io.BytesIO` takes a byte string and returns a byte stream. `io.StringIO`, on the other hand, would take a Unicode string and and return a Unicode stream.
- `x` gets assigned a string literal, which in Python 3.x is a Unicode string.
- `encode()` takes the Unicode string `x` and makes a byte string out of it, thus giving `io.BytesIO` a valid argument.

The only difference for Python 2.6/2.7 is that `x` is a byte string (assuming `from __future__ import unicode_literals` is not used), and then `encode()` takes the byte string `x` and still makes the same byte string out of it. So the result is the same.

---

Since this is one of SO's most popular questions regarding `StringIO`, here's some more explanation on the import statements and different Python versions.

Here are the classes which take a string and return a stream:

- [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) (Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.x) - Takes a byte string. Returns a byte stream.
- [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o) (Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.x) - Takes a Unicode string. Returns a Unicode stream.
- [`StringIO.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#) (Python 2.x) - Takes a byte string or Unicode string. If byte string, returns a byte stream. If Unicode string, returns a Unicode stream.
- [`cStringIO.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) (Python 2.x) - Faster version of `StringIO.StringIO`, but can't take Unicode strings which contain non-ASCII characters.

Note that `StringIO.StringIO` is imported as `from StringIO import StringIO`, then used as `StringIO(...)`. Either that, or you do `import StringIO` and then use `StringIO.StringIO(...)`. The module name and class name just happen to be the same. It's similar to `datetime` that way.

What to use, depending on your supported Python versions:

- *If you only support Python 3.x:* Just use `io.BytesIO` or `io.StringIO` depending on what kind of data you're working with.
- *If you support both Python 2.6/2.7 and 3.x, or are trying to transition your code from 2.6/2.7 to 3.x:* The easiest option is still to use `io.BytesIO` or `io.StringIO`. Although `StringIO.StringIO` is flexible and thus seems preferred for 2.6/2.7, that flexibility could mask bugs that will manifest in 3.x. For example, I had some code which used `StringIO.StringIO` or `io.StringIO` depending on Python version, but I was actually passing a byte string, so when I got around to testing it in Python 3.x it failed and had to be fixed.

  Another advantage of using `io.StringIO` is the support for universal newlines. If you pass the keyword argument `newline=''` into `io.StringIO`, it will be able to split lines on any of `\n`, `\r\n`, or `\r`. I found that `StringIO.StringIO` would trip up on `\r` in particular.

  Note that if you import `BytesIO` or `StringIO` from [`six`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/), you get `StringIO.StringIO` in Python 2.x and the appropriate class from `io` in Python 3.x. If you agree with my previous paragraphs' assessment, this is actually one case where you should avoid `six` and just import from `io` instead.
- *If you support Python 2.5 or lower and 3.x:* You'll need `StringIO.StringIO` for 2.5 or lower, so you might as well use `six`. But realize that it's generally very difficult to support both 2.5 and 3.x, so you should consider bumping your lowest supported version to 2.6 if at all possible.

Answer (score 26):

Thank you OP for your question, and Roman for your answer. I had to search a bit to find this; I hope the following helps others.

**Python 2.7**

See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html

```
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

data = "1, abc , 2\n 3, xxx, 4"

print type(data)
"""
<type 'str'>
"""

print '\n', np.genfromtxt(StringIO(data), delimiter=",", dtype="|S3", autostrip=True)
"""
[['1' 'abc' '2']
 ['3' 'xxx' '4']]
"""

print '\n', type(data)
"""
<type 'str'>
"""

print '\n', np.genfromtxt(StringIO(data), delimiter=",", autostrip=True)
"""
[[  1.  nan   2.]
 [  3.  nan   4.]]
"""
```

**Python 3.5:**

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
import io

data = "1, abc , 2\n 3, xxx, 4"
#print(data)
"""
1, abc , 2
 3, xxx, 4
"""

#print(type(data))
"""
<class 'str'>
"""

#np.genfromtxt(StringIO(data), delimiter=",", autostrip=True)
# TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

print('\n')
print(np.genfromtxt(io.BytesIO(data.encode()), delimiter=",", dtype="|S3", autostrip=True))
"""
[[b'1' b'abc' b'2']
 [b'3' b'xxx' b'4']]
"""

print('\n')
print(np.genfromtxt(io.BytesIO(data.encode()), delimiter=",", autostrip=True))
"""
[[  1.  nan   2.]
 [  3.  nan   4.]]
"""
```

**Aside:**

dtype="|Sx", where x = any of { 1, 2, 3, ...}:

[dtypes. Difference between S1 and S2 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790130/dtypes-difference-between-s1-and-s2-in-python)

"The |S1 and |S2 strings are data type descriptors; the first means the array holds strings of length 1, the second of length 2. ..."

Answer (score 24):

You can use the [StringIO](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.StringIO) from the [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) module:

```
import six
import numpy

x = "1 3\n 4.5 8"
numpy.genfromtxt(six.StringIO(x))
```

Answer (score 7):

In order to make examples from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html)
work with Python 3.5.2, you can rewrite as follows :

```
import io
data =io.BytesIO(b"1, 2, 3\n4, 5, 6") 
import numpy
numpy.genfromtxt(data, delimiter=",")
```

The reason for the change may be that the content of a file is in data (bytes) which do not make text until being decoded somehow. `genfrombytes` may be a better name than `genfromtxt`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example for **Python 3**. It will use two functions to add two numbers and then use CProfile to save the `.prof` file. Then it will load the save file using `pstats.Stats` and ```StringIO`` to convert the data to a string for further usage.

#### main.py

```py
import cProfile
import time
import pstats
from io import StringIO

def add_slow(a, b):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return a+b

def add_fast(a, b):
    return a+b

prof = cProfile.Profile()

def main_func():
    arr = []
    prof.enable()
    for i in range(10):
        if i%2==0:
            arr.append(add_slow(i,i))
        else:
            arr.append(add_fast(i,i))
    prof.disable()
    #prof.print_stats(sort='time')
    prof.dump_stats("main_funcs.prof")
    return arr

main_func()
stream = StringIO();
stats = pstats.Stats("main_funcs.prof", stream=stream); 
stats.print_stats()
stream.seek(0)
print(16*'=',"RESULTS",16*'=')
print (stream.read())
```

Usage:

```
python3 main.py
```

Output:

```
================ RESULTS ================
Tue Jul  6 17:36:21 2021    main_funcs.prof

         26 function calls in 2.507 seconds

   Random listing order was used

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        5    2.507    0.501    2.507    0.501 {built-in method time.sleep}
        5    0.000    0.000    2.507    0.501 profiler.py:39(add_slow)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 profiler.py:43(add_fast)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comments: We can observe that in the above code, the time.sleep function is taking about 2.507 seconds.

Answer (score -2):

**I hope this will meet your requirement**

```
import PyPDF4
import io

pdfFile = open(r'test.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(1)
pagetext = pageObj.extractText()

for line in io.StringIO(pagetext):
    print(line)
```