# Changing image type in Django

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

I have an image of `ImageFieldFile` type in Django. If I do `print type(image)`, I get `<class 'django.db.models.fields.files.ImageFieldFile'>`

Next, I opened this using PIL's `Image.open(image)`, resized it via `image.resize((20,20))` and closed it `image.close()`.

After closing it, I notice image's *type* has changed to `<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>`.

How do I change it back to `<class 'django.db.models.fields.files.ImageFieldFile'>`? I thought `.close()` would suffice.

Comment: Why do you need to change it back? Is there a bigger problem here?

Comment: Saving it on Azure storage blob, where I keep getting a type error for `<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>`, but not for `<class 'django.db.models.fields.files.ImageFieldFile'>`

Comment: This perhaps won't be much of a help, but check some ways of editing images while uploading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519716/django-resize-image-during-upload and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373341/django-image-resizing-and-convert-before-upload

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035833/how-to-go-form-django-image-field-to-pil-image-and-back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I got around this was to save it to a `BytesIO` object then stuff that into an `InMemoryUploadedFile`.  So something like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile

# Where image is your ImageFieldFile
pil_image = Image.open(image)
pil_image.resize((20, 20))

image_bytes = BytesIO()
pil_image.save(image_bytes)

new_image = InMemoryUploadedFile(
    image_bytes, None, image.name, image.type, None, None, None
)
image_bytes.close()
```

Not terribly graceful, but it got the job done.  This was done in Python 3.  Not sure of Python 2 compatibility.

EDIT:

Actually, in hindsight, [I like this answer better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035833/how-to-go-form-django-image-field-to-pil-image-and-back#answer-28209277).  Wish it existed when I was trying to solve this issue.  :-\

Hope this helps.  Cheers!