# How can I get Ruby's Regexp to work in Heroku without Internal Server Error?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have this program that I have managed to upload to heroku without error. But when I open it in the browser, then if I keep in there a line that uses Regexp, I get "internal server error". If I comment it out it's fine.

I have looked at similarly titled questions about Heroku giving "internal server error", but they don't involve Regexp, and they haven't given me any ideas as to what I need to do to make it work. For example [Heroku deployment internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273687/heroku-deployment-internal-server-error)  the person was using python and a package he had installed was incompatible, that doesn't seem relevant to my issue.   This one [Heroku + Django Internal server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535475/heroku-django-internal-server-error)  a guy had to import something called djcelery. Well, maybe I have to import something somewhere, but I don't know what, but it wouldn't be djcelery 'cos i'm not using django.

```
C:\rubytest\regexinheroku1>dir /b
aaa.rb
config.ru
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock

C:\rubytest\regexinheroku1>
```

here is aaa.rb

```
C:\rubytest\regexinheroku1>type aaa.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
z=Regexp.new('.').match?('qwerty')   
"aaaa"
end
```

This succeeds

```
C:\rubytest\regexinheroku1>git push heroku master

.... deployed to Heroku
```

Here is the problem though

If I go to the URL, it says "Internal Server Error"

[image]

However, if I change aaa.rb by commenting out the regexp line

```
C:\rubytest\regexinheroku1>type aaa.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
# z=Regexp.new('.').match?('qwerty')   
"aaaa"
end
```

Then it works fine, a page comes up and says "aaaa" as expected.

If you want to reproduce this and the above isn't enough, here are all the steps

```
So you see the files

C:\rubytest\regexinheroku2>dir /b
aaa.rb
config.ru
Gemfile

The contents of each file 

C:\rubytest\regexinheroku2>type aaa.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
z=Regexp.new('.').match?('qwerty')  # if I uncomment this, I get internal server error
"aaaa"
end


C:\rubytest\regexinheroku2>type config.ru
require './aaa'
run Sinatra::Application
C:\rubytest\regexinheroku2>

C:\rubytest\regexinheroku2>type Gemfile
source "http://rubygems.org/"
gem 'sinatra'
gem "haml"

And see the commands I run to get the application successfully deployed

C:\rubytest\regexinheroku2>bundle install
...

C:\rubytest\regexinheroku2>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/rubytest/regexinheroku2/.git/

C:\rubytest\regexinheroku2>git add -A
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Gemfile.lock.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

C:\rubytest\regexinheroku2>git commit -m "sddsfsdfsd"
[master (root-commit) 12cf382] sddsfsdfsd
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Gemfile.lock.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
 4 files changed, 39 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 Gemfile
 create mode 100644 Gemfile.lock
 create mode 100644 aaa.rb
 create mode 100644 config.ru

C:\rubytest\regexinheroku2>heroku create
path1 gitmisc done
Creating app... done,   abc
https://abc.herokuapp.com/ | ....

C:\rubytest\regexinheroku2>git push heroku master
....
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/abc.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master

C:\rubytest\regexinheroku2>
```

Comment: What does your error log say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all errors, the first thing to do is *check the log*. The log should (almost) always provide a better clue to the error than the generic "internal server error" that's public-facing.

However, in this case I'm almost certain the issue is that your local machine is using **ruby version `>= 2.4.0`** (possibly `2.5.1`, which is the latest?), whereas heroku is running **ruby version `2.3.7`**. From [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#default-ruby-version-for-new-apps):

> If your `Gemfile` does not contain a ruby entry, you will get `MRI 2.3.7` on `Cedar-14` and `Heroku-16` stacks. On `Heroku-18` you will get `MRI 2.4.4`.

To fix this, I would recommend including:

```
ruby '2.5.1'
```

(or whatever version you're using) in the `Gemfile`. This is good practice in general, as it ensures your local and production environments are the same.

The actual issue here, to be specific, is that [Ruby `2.4.0` added the method `Regexp#match?`](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/11/04/ruby-2-4-implements-regexp-match-without-polluting-global-variables.html). So Heroku is currently throwing an "unknown method" error.

Comment: yeah thanks, makes sense. The log says `NoMethodError - undefined method 'match?' for /a/:Regexp`   so you're right

Comment: Two things worth adding to that A)To check the log do heroku logs B)Your solution of writing `ruby '2.5.1'` in the Gemfile is brilliant and lets me use `match?`. As an alternative to your solution, I can write `Regexp.new('.').match('abcdefg')[0]` which is consistent with an early ruby version https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Regexp.html#method-i-match  But your solution is better.