# How to return a qrcode (pillow image) from cherrypy as PNG without saving it as a static file?

Tags: python-2.7, qr-code, cherrypy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode) qrcode library to generate a png
containing a qrcode. I want to use cherrypy to serve this image
dynamically.

qrcode draws on the PIL/Pillow library, so I strongly suspect that
the img in the code below works the same way as a pillow image:
When I test this by printing it manually I get this.

```
>>> print(img)
<qrcode.image.pil.PilImage object at 0xcb2c90>
```

This is the code I have in cherrypy to create a qrcode dynamically.
This code does not work.

```
@cp.expose
def qrcode(self, ticketnumber = 'unknown'):

    img = qrcode.make(ticketnumber)

    # this works:
    # img.save('local.png')

    cp.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"

    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    # this is a guess and not working
    img.save(buffer, format='PNG')
    buffer.seek(0)

    return file_generator(buffer)
```

Any idea on how to return the PIL/pillow image without saving it as a static file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more googling I got the syntax right.
The example below works

```
@cp.expose
def qrcode(self, ticketnumber = 'unknown'):
    img = qrcode.make(ticketnumber)
    cp.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(buffer, 'PNG')
    return buffer.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 0):

For python3: note that there is no more StringIO, refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914472/how-to-use-stringio-in-python3#18284900)

Replacing above `buffer = StringIO.StringIO()` with `buffer = io.BytesIO()` works for me.