# Matplotlib graphic image to base64

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

**Problem :** Need to transform a graphic image of matplotlib to a base64 image

**Current Solution :** Save the matplot image in a cache folder and read it with read() method and then convert to base64

**New Problem : Annoyance :** Need a workaround so I dont need to save the graphic as image in any folder. I want to just use the image in the memory. Doing unnecessary I/O is a bad practice.

```
def save_single_graphic_data(data, y_label="Loss", x_label="Epochs", save_as="data.png"):
    total_epochs = len(data)
    plt.figure()
    plt.clf()

    plt.plot(total_epochs, data)

    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

    plt.ylabel(y_label)
    plt.xlabel(x_label)

    if save_as is not None:
        plt.savefig(save_as)

    plt.savefig("cache/cached1.png")

    cached_img = open("cache/cached1.png")

    cached_img_b64 = base64.b64encode(cached_img.read())

    os.remove("cache/cached1.png")

    return cached_img_b64
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
import cStringIO
my_stringIObytes = cStringIO.StringIO()
plt.savefig(my_stringIObytes, format='jpg')
my_stringIObytes.seek(0)
my_base64_jpgData = base64.b64encode(my_stringIObytes.read())
```

[edit] in python3 it should be

```
import io
my_stringIObytes = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(my_stringIObytes, format='jpg')
my_stringIObytes.seek(0)
my_base64_jpgData = base64.b64encode(my_stringIObytes.read()).decode()
```

I think at least ... based on the documentation http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig

Comment: If you are using Python 3 or greater, you need to use `io.BytesIO` as mentioned by @nobar at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18284900/1802726.

Comment: Or for Python 2/3 compatibility with fastest implementation: `try: from cStringIO import StringIO; except ImportError: from six import StringIO` ([`six` ref](https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.StringIO))

Comment: Hi Joran, from your code, where is the figure variable? I only see my_stringIObytes, I don't see any variable related to original mtaplotlib plot object. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: `my_base64_jpgData` has the base64 encoded  data you could then do something like

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{my_base64_jpgData}" />`   or use other methods to decode it back to the original image

Comment: `my_base64_jpgData ` might have to be wrapped in an `str()`, as the data is in binary string format by default. ( `b'sfsafs'`)

Comment: 05.05.23 - Linked here via another question. This contributed to helping me solve my issue. +1

Comment: @roudan I had the same question--it worked when I replaced `plt.savefig(...)` with `my_figure.savefig(...)`

Answer (score 26):

For python 3

```
import base64
import io 
pic_IObytes = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(pic_IObytes,  format='png')
pic_IObytes.seek(0)
pic_hash = base64.b64encode(pic_IObytes.read())
```

The reason is both `cStringIO` and `cStringIO.StringIO()` are deprecated

Comment: You might want to add a more detailed explanation

Comment: @YuliaV what I was saying is that in Python 3 the ```cStringIO``` module has been deprecated in place of ```io``` module. So that is why I used the io module in my answer.

Answer (score 20):

I could not get answers above work, but this did:

```
    import io
    import base64
    s = io.BytesIO()
    plt.plot(list(range(100)))
    plt.savefig(s, format='png', bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.close()
    s = base64.b64encode(s.getvalue()).decode("utf-8").replace("\n", "")
    return '<img align="left" src="data:image/png;base64,%s">' % s
```

Comment: is it the fastest solution ?