# how to import data in jupiter notebook from an online csv file which is in zip file

Tags: machine-learning

How can i import data from a online zip file to jupiter notebook .
like the data is on

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00320/

this link and i want to import it to jupiter notebook to work on it .So thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib import urlopen

url = urlopen("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00320/student.zip")

z = ZipFile(StringIO(url.read()))

for line in z.open("student-por.csv").readlines():
     print line
```

Comment: Its showing error    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-889eb2aa625b> in <module>()
----> 1 from StringIO import StringIO

ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'

Comment: You will have to install StringIO package

Comment: If you are using python3 refer:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914472/stringio-in-python3