# Import CSV to pandas with two delimiters

Tags: python, csv, pandas, delimiter, csv-import

I have a CSV with two delimiters (`;`) and (`,`) it looks like this:

```
vin;vorgangid;eventkm;D_8_lamsoni_w_time;D_8_lamsoni_w_value
V345578;295234545;13;-1000.0,-980.0;7.9921875,11.984375
V346670;329781064;13;-960.0,-940.0;7.9921875,11.984375
```

I want to import it into a pandas data frame, with the (`;`) acting as a column separator and (`,`) as a separator for a `list` or `array` using `float` as data type. So far I am using this method, but I am sure there is something easier out there.

```
aa=0;
csv_import=pd.read_csv(folder+FileName, ';')
for col in csv_import.columns:
aa=aa+1
if type(csv_import[col][0])== str and aa>3:
    # string to list of strings
    csv_import[col]=csv_import[col].apply(lambda x:x.split(','))
    # make the list of stings into a list of floats
    csv_import[col]=csv_import[col].apply(lambda x: [float(y) for y in x])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asides from the other fine answers here, which are more pandas-specific, it should be noted that Python itself is pretty powerful when it comes to string processing. You can just place the result of replacing `';'` with `','` in a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object, and work normally from there:

```
In [8]: import pandas as pd

In [9]: from cStringIO import StringIO

In [10]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(''.join(l.replace(';', ',') for l in open('stuff.csv'))))
Out[10]: 
                   vin  vorgangid  eventkm  D_8_lamsoni_w_time  \
V345578 295234545   13    -1000.0   -980.0            7.992188   
V346670 329781064   13     -960.0   -940.0            7.992188   

                   D_8_lamsoni_w_value  
V345578 295234545            11.984375  
V346670 329781064            11.984375
```

Comment: Interesting approach, how does this work in Python 3.5?
import io
pd.read_csv(io(''.join(l.replace(';', ',') for l in open('stuff.csv'))))
does not work

Comment: @valenzio I just checked this on 3.5.2, and it's exactly the same.

Comment: I get the massage, No module named 'cStringIO'
do I have to install that module via pip, I had a feeling it comes with python

Comment: @valenzio Sorry - bad phrasing on my part. The code is the same, but the import is different. You need to [`from io import StringIO`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914472/stringio-in-python3).

Comment: Thank you it works now, but for some reason the column names are shifted and for each entry you get a single column. Your approach is the closest solution I was thinking of. I will try and undstand the syntax and maybe with some manipulation I will find the solution.

Comment: @valenzio OK, good luck. Feel free to post, if you find something interesting (by me, it seems to work, but there's always something to learn).

Answer (score 3):

first read CSV using `;` as a delimiter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [67]: num_cols = df.columns.difference(['vin','vorgangid','eventkm'])

In [68]: num_cols
Out[68]: Index(['D_8_lamsoni_w_time', 'D_8_lamsoni_w_value'], dtype='object')

In [69]: df[num_cols] = (df[num_cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',', expand=True)
   ....:                                               .stack()
   ....:                                               .astype(float)
   ....:                                               .unstack()
   ....:                                               .values.tolist())
   ....:                )

In [70]: df
Out[70]:
       vin  vorgangid  eventkm D_8_lamsoni_w_time     D_8_lamsoni_w_value
0  V345578  295234545       13  [-1000.0, -980.0]  [7.9921875, 11.984375]
1  V346670  329781064       13   [-960.0, -940.0]  [7.9921875, 11.984375]

In [71]: type(df.loc[0, 'D_8_lamsoni_w_value'][0])
Out[71]: float
```

**OLD answer:**

Now we can split numbers into lists in the "number" columns:

```
In [20]: df[['D_8_lamsoni_w_time',  'D_8_lamsoni_w_value']] = \
    df[['D_8_lamsoni_w_time',  'D_8_lamsoni_w_value']].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(','))
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
       vin  vorgangid  eventkm D_8_lamsoni_w_time     D_8_lamsoni_w_value
0  V345578  295234545       13  [-1000.0, -980.0]  [7.9921875, 11.984375]
1  V346670  329781064       13   [-960.0, -940.0]  [7.9921875, 11.984375]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have 2 comments:
1) I guess line [20] can be packed into a for loop if you have way more than 2 columns, but than it becomes basically the same as my approach, no?
2) I think at the end you still end up with a list of strings e.g. type(df.ix[0,4][0]) == 'str'

Comment: @valenzio, please check the UPDATE section - i've completely rewritten the code and addressed both your questions

Comment: Thanks mate, this looks much better, but you would still need two for loops if you have like 100 entries for line 67 and 68, I was looking for a solution similar what Ami Tavory suggested. Basically one import command with the right parameters

Comment: @valenzio, no, no additional loops are needed

Comment: @ MaxU, well think about this way: the data I provided is just a small portion to make it more readable. In reality I have over 100 columns with different names, so I would need on for loop to create 'num_cols' and one to assign the different columns with the new data type.

Comment: @valenzio, that's the point! `df.columns.difference(['vin','vorgangid','eventkm'])` - will give you __ALL__ columns except `['vin','vorgangid','eventkm']` and `df[num_cols] = (df[num_cols].apply(...)` will process __ALL__ columns (in the `num_cols` list) in one step

Answer (score 2):

You can use parameter `converters` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and define custom function for spliting:

```
def f(x):
    return [float(i) for i in x.split(',')]

#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep=";", 
                 converters={'D_8_lamsoni_w_time':f, 'D_8_lamsoni_w_value':f})
print (df)
       vin  vorgangid  eventkm D_8_lamsoni_w_time     D_8_lamsoni_w_value
0  V345578  295234545       13  [-1000.0, -980.0]  [7.9921875, 11.984375]
1  V346670  329781064       13   [-960.0, -940.0]  [7.9921875, 11.984375]
```

Another solution working with `NaN` in `4.` and `5.` columns:

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with separators `;`, then apply [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to `4.` and `5.` column selected by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and convert each value in `list` to `float`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

temp=u"""vin;vorgangid;eventkm;D_8_lamsoni_w_time;D_8_lamsoni_w_value
V345578;295234545;13;-1000.0,-980.0;7.9921875,11.984375
V346670;329781064;13;-960.0,-940.0;7.9921875,11.984375"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";")

print (df)
       vin  vorgangid  eventkm D_8_lamsoni_w_time  D_8_lamsoni_w_value
0  V345578  295234545       13     -1000.0,-980.0  7.9921875,11.984375
1  V346670  329781064       13      -960.0,-940.0  7.9921875,11.984375

#split 4.th and 5th column and convert to numpy array
df.iloc[:,3] = df.iloc[:,3].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: [float(i) for i in x])
df.iloc[:,4] = df.iloc[:,4].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: [float(i) for i in x])
print (df)
       vin  vorgangid  eventkm D_8_lamsoni_w_time     D_8_lamsoni_w_value
0  V345578  295234545       13  [-1000.0, -980.0]  [7.9921875, 11.984375]
1  V346670  329781064       13   [-960.0, -940.0]  [7.9921875, 11.984375]
```

If need `numpy arrays` instead `lists`:

```
#split 4.th and 5th column and convert to numpy array
df.iloc[:,3] = df.iloc[:,3].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: np.array([float(i) for i in x]))
df.iloc[:,4] = df.iloc[:,4].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: np.array([float(i) for i in x]))
print (df)
       vin  vorgangid  eventkm D_8_lamsoni_w_time     D_8_lamsoni_w_value
0  V345578  295234545       13  [-1000.0, -980.0]  [7.9921875, 11.984375]
1  V346670  329781064       13   [-960.0, -940.0]  [7.9921875, 11.984375]

print (type(df.iloc[0,3]))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

---

I try improve your solutiuon:

```
a=0;
csv_import=pd.read_csv(folder+FileName, ';')
for col in csv_import.columns:
    a += 1
    if type(csv_import.ix[0, col])== str and a>3:
        # string to list of strings
        csv_import[col]=csv_import[col].apply(lambda x: [float(y) for y in x.split(',')])
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but correct me if I am wrong, this looks more tedious than my approach. Cheers

Comment: Ok, I try improve your solution, please check last paragraph in my answer.

Comment: looking good, but I guess there is no way to avoid the for loop, I just thought there is a way to initialize the import in some way that it automatically knows that (',') seperated values are an array

Comment: No, I think you need my first solution with `formaters` if need convert to list some columns.