# Read txt file of this type in as a Python numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy, delimiter

I'd like to perform some dimension-reduction (DR) methods such as PCA, ICA and tSNE, maybe LEM on the a data set data.txt to compare the methods.

Therefore, I need to read in the data as a numpy.ndarray.
Every line corresponds to a row in the matrix, with delimiter = ' '.

Alternatively, I have the file as a numpy.array now but as a string:

> [ '16.72083152\t12.91868366\t14.37818919\n'
>   ...
>   '16.9504402\t7.81951173\t12.81342726']

How can I convert this quickly into a numpy.array of the desired format: n x 3, delimiter for rows = ' ', delimiter between elements in each row = '\t' chopping the '\n' at the end?

A quick answer much appreciated. Other tips as well. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest that you look into the Pandas library, which has many tools for parsing textual datafiles and data analysis, and also scikit-learn which has more sophisticated dimension-reduction and clustering techniques.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
import numpy 
try: from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError: from io import StringIO

foo = '16.72083152\t12.91868366\t14.37818919\n16.9504402\t7.81951173\t12.81342726\n'
fn = StringIO.StringIO(foo) #make a file object from the string
data = numpy.loadtxt(fn) #use loadtxt with default settings.
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like there is no module "StringIO" for me. I am using version 3.6.3

Comment: use `io` instead of `stringio` per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914472/stringio-in-python3

Comment: but the answer @era_misa obviates that

Answer (score 2):

you could just try below code:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt',delimiter='\t')
```